# What is a StickyLabel, and why does it sit in a ContextMenuStrip.Contols collection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` which is tight to a `ListView`, and made of a combination of various `ToolStripMenuItem` and `ToolStripSeparator`.
I would like this context menu to hide/show some if these controls, depending on the current status of the `ListView` (no item in the view, only 1 item selected, more than 1 item selected).
The `ListView` is part of a UserControl which is loaded in Ms Word via an application-level VSTO AddIn.

At the moment, my strategy was to rely on the `.tag` property of the controls  and to run a switch over this property for each control in the context menu.
It looks like this:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems_Opening(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems.Opening

    Dim ThisListView As ListView = ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems.SourceControl

    For Each MyControl As ToolStripItem In ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems.Controls

        MyControl.Visible = False

        Select Case CType(MyControl.Tag, String)
            Case "ShowAlways"
                MyControl.Visible = True
            Case "WhenSelection"
                If ThisListView.FocusedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso ThisListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                    MyControl.Visible = True
                End If
            Case "WhenSingleSelection"
                If ThisListView.FocusedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso ThisListView.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
                    MyControl.Visible = True
                End If
            Case "WhenMultipleSelection"
                If ThisListView.FocusedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso ThisListView.SelectedItems.Count > 1 Then
                    MyControl.Visible = True
                End If
            Case Else
                Throw New ApplicationException("The control tag property is not recognized.")
        End Select

    Next

End Sub
```

When I right click on the `ListView`, I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'StickyLabel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem'.'

at the line: `For Each MyControl As ToolStripItem In ContextMenuStrip_FilesToPopulate.Control`.

I did not find any documentation nor responses on google when searching for "StickyLabel". And I do not understand why it is trying to cast it in my ForeEach loop, instead of just skipping it?

Comment: StickyLabel is an [implementation detail](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripScrollButton.cs,45) of a ToolStripScrollButton.  Not what you want to see back when you write "should work for any menu item" code, iterate the Items property instead.  Notable how the ToolStrip classes were training wheels for the WPF team.

Comment: Yes, as often happens, I got stuck for hours but figured out minutes after asking the questions on SO.. the documentation on `.Controls` is quite misleading (why is it not a private field?). Thanks for the link though!

Comment: *"the documentation on .Controls is quite misleading"*. Um, no.  The documentation for that property is completely on point.  It says *"This property is not relevant for this class"*.  How is that misleading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For Each MyControl As ToolStripItem In ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems.Controls`

should be changed to

`For Each MyControl As ToolStripItem In ContextMenuStrip_PopulatedItems.Items`.

However, I am still interested to understand what is happening behind the scenes with this StickyLabel.

Comment: As with all controls, the `Controls` property is a collection of all child controls.  Why does it seem such a mystery that a menu control might need a child control that is not one of the menu items in order to make it work in the desired manner?

Answer (score 1):

Those Labels are used for ToolStripDropDown List, that exceed the display size. You get a button to the top end bottom of the list, which scroll through the list in the appropriate direction.